# on running selenium test through gitlab ci cd pipeline extend report not generating

Tags: selenium, testng, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am generating the extend report & I have written code to mail that report to respective person. Locally it is working fine but I have to run same through CI CD pipeline in git lab. but getting below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvv1L.png)

```
email exception ********javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
2056  nested exception is:
2057    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /builds/oe/apps/cce/cce-support-apps/dell-ccx-ui-automation\HtmlResults\14_04_2021_10_46_42.html (No such file or directory)
```

It seems extend report not generating. Please let me know how to generate the extend report through CI CD pipeline in git lab.

Answer (score 0):

I can see path with slash **\ , /** differs.

```
/builds/oe/apps/cce/cce-support-apps/dell-ccx-ui-automation\HtmlResults\14_04_2021_10_46_42.html
```

It should be looking something like this

```
/builds/oe/apps/cce/cce-support-apps/dell-ccx-ui-automation/HtmlResults/14_04_2021_10_46_42.html
```